# How to return this query in supabase function

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, supabase, supabase-database

I have a table called **helper** which have columns id(text), title(varchar), tags(varchar), author_name(varchar), profile_pic(varchar), created_at(timestampz)

I made a supabase function:

```
create or replace function hello(si text)
returns setof ________ as $$
  begin
    return query select *, 1 as "priority"
      from helper
      where to_tsvector(title) @@ to_tsquery(si)
      union
      select *, 0 as "priority"
      from helper
      where to_tsvector(tags) @@ to_tsquery(si)
      order by "priority" desc;
  end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

What do i have to put at underlined position to get the appropriate result.
If I put helper, and call it in the supabase sql editor then I would get an error:

```
Failed to run sql query: structure of query does not match function result type
```

What I want to achieve with all of this?

I want to make a searching functionality, where I want to search 'searched text' in the 'title' column first, and then in 'tags' column. After than I want to order the result in such a manner where matched results with title comes first and matched results with tag comes later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning records that would fit into `helper` because you're adding the `"priority"` column, hence the structure mismatch exception. Instead of `setof helper` you'll have to use an explicit list of columns, with the new one added. As a bonus, you can easily switch to plain `language sql` to gain some performance:

```sql
create or replace function hello(si text)
returns table (
    id text, 
    title varchar,
    tags varchar,
    author_name varchar,
    profile_pic varchar,
    created_at timestampz,
    priority int) 
language sql as $$
    select *, 1 as "priority"
    from helper
    where to_tsvector(title) @@ to_tsquery(si)
    union
    select *, 0 as "priority"
    from helper
    where to_tsvector(tags) @@ to_tsquery(si)
    order by "priority" desc;
$$;
```

It's tempting to use `returns table (like helper, priority int)` that would normally work for a [`create table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#:%7E:text=the%20parent%20table.-,LIKE,-source_table%20%5B%20like_option) where you wish to create an identical one, just adding one column, but in this case it later results in an error on calls to a function defined that way:

```sql
ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return record
DETAIL:  Final statement returns text instead of helper at column 1.
```

Workarounds using an intermediate table or view don't make it dynamic the way `returns table (like helper)` would (making the function result structure follow the table structure if it changes in the future), so it's not worth it.
[Online examples](https://dbfiddle.uk/WmElslaN)